# Weird looking text and icons in top bar

Tags: 12.04, fonts, antialiasing

[image]

Look at "Google - Mozilla Firefox"

There are ugly pixels around text and icons in top bar and it's very annoying. It looks like bad antialiasing or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an antialiasing bug only in the top bar of the **Unity** environment when using the **Radiance** theme instead of the default theme **Ambiance**. In all other places the text will be fine. You can install `gnome-tweak-tool` and try different fonts for using in the titlebar, change antialiasing, hinting, etc. to see better results.

Comment: Why not include [a link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/), or an image: `![image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U4mKR.png)` ;-)